# How to convert this sql to efcore linq

Tags: c#, linq

Original data sheet：

[image]

SQL that can get the result you want：

```
select group_number,count(group_number) as group_count,receive_date 
from hS_HZXX 
where type = '1' 
group by group_number,receive_date;
```

[image]

use ef core linq like this:

```
var hAATGroups = from p in dbContext.Set<HS_HZXX>()
                         where p.type == "1"
                         group p by new { Group_number = p.group_number, Sampling_date = p.sampling_date } into dto
                         select new DTO_HAATGroup
                         {
                             Group_number = dto.Key.Group_number,
                             HAAT_count = dto.Key.Group_number.Count(),
                             Sampling_date = dto.Key.Sampling_date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
                         };
```

The DTO_HAATGroup:

```
public class DTO_HAATGroup
{

    public string Group_number { get; set; }
    public int HAAT_count { set; get; }
    public string Sampling_date { get; set; }

}
```

The result of executing linq:

[image]

But I got the wrong result. . . Can you help me? How can I convert this SQL into a correct Linq statement.

Comment: Its hard to trust a question about conversion, when the convert from code contains `whhere`

Comment: Please provide example input and output for both the sql-statement and the linq-statement

Comment: I think you need to count on the `dto` and not the value of `a`

Comment: Why are you using `.Set<HS_HZXX>()` instead of a proper DbSet property? You can't even use `Set<>()` without configuring the entities, so what's the point? As for using a *string* for a date, that's a major database design bug. `String.ToString()` just returns the string itself so `Sampling_date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")` is meaningless and won't even compile

Comment: Post your *actual* code, actual table schema, sample data and expected results as. *text*, not images. The screenshots don't match the code. The code can't compile. Images can't be copied and executed either

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem, the correct Linq writing is as follows:

```
        var hAATGroups = from p in dbContext.Set<HS_HZXX>()
                         where p.type == "1"
                         group p by new { Group_number = p.group_number, Receive_date = p.receive_date } into dto
                         select new DTO_HAATGroup
                         {
                             Group_number = dto.Key.Group_number,
                             HAAT_count = dto.Count(),
                             Receive_date = dto.Key.Receive_date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
                         };
```

Comment: There was no `Receive_date` property in the code you posted

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos  Receive_date is actually an attribute in the HS_HZXX entity. Of course it also contains a Sampling_date attribute, which I made a mistake before. Mainly to solve the problem of count(). Thank you for your reply.